# Pandas scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas

Im new to Python and Pandas but have a CSV file with multiple columns that I have read in to a dataframe.  I would like to plot a scatter plot of x=Index and y='data'. Where the index is Index of the dataframe and is a date.
Thanks heaps
Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot_date#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date):

```
plot_date(df.index, df.data)
```

Comment: Great.  I'd didnt realise it was as simple as passing df.index.  I was having trouble because I was trying to use the column names but the index doesnt have a column name.

Comment: I would use `df.plot()', would be more "pandas-like".

Comment: @bmu trying to scatter plot with datetimes is not as straightforward as you might expect.  You will end up with KeyErrors if you attempt to provide datetimes as the x in `df.plot()` and you'll notice [`pd.Series.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html#pandas.Series.plot) has no 'scatter' argument for `kind`.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst, I guess technically not a scatter plot, you can use the `pandas.plot` function with point markers drawn on and no lines.

```
df.plot(marker='o', linewidth=0)
```

[image]

This then allows us to use all of the convenient pandas functionality you desire. e.g. plot two series and different scales, using a single function,

```
df.plot(marker='o', linewidth=0, secondary_y='y2')
```

[image]

The downside to this is that you lose some of the scatter functionality such as shading and sizing the markers differently.

Still, if your aim is a quick scatter plot, this might be the easiest route.